# Is there caching in templating function in Magnolia?

Tags: magnolia

Is there a caching for the templating function in Magnolia? I created a custom templating function with a function that retrieves data from a specific workspace. I put logs in it to know if it is entering the function that I want to call, but seems like even if I call the function I created in the templating function, I don't see the logs, thus it will get the previous data that I have. Then what I notice is that, when I've updated something on that workspace, then when I call the function, it will enter that function and give me the updated data.

So is there caching or what? Is there a way to disable this? It was my first time to notice this so I find it a bit weird also because in my local dev environment, I can always see that it always enter to the function whenever it is called. However the one deployed in our UAT environment, when I check the logs, it doesn't always enter to the function for every call. So I'm quite lost here.

I'm using Magnolia 5.4.7.

Appreciate it a lot if anyone can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue. Yeah there's really a cache. So what I did is I exclude my page for being cache so when I call the templating function in my page, it will return me the latest one.

Also, this caching only happens in delivery instance.  That's why in my local environment it was working because I'm actually using the author instance to test! That's made the difference.

You have to configure your custom cache policy under "/modules/cache/config/configuration/default/cachepolicy" of the config workspace. For more information, please check: https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS53/Cache+module , read the "Excluding content from cache" for this